# Apollo Client/GraphQL updating the UI in real time

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have a form in which i'm trying to create a user experience that when you are creating a new record, it will create an id for it and write to the database in real time, and reflect those changes in the UI.
OR
You are editing a record, it is already given a id, so it knows to update the record.

I have a mutation that handles this with 2 cases:

There is no ID passed to the mutation, so it creates a new one.

It's passed an ID , so it updates that object.

The component is using compose to wrap the 2 case mutation, and also a query for that object.
I have tried attaching a fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network', but that doesnt work.

Intended outcome:
Trying to get back an id generated in a component action

Actual outcome:
ID shows up null when re rendering component, only updates upon page refresh

How to reproduce the issue:
I have a mutation that either creates a new id for an object if it's not passed a previous id.
Or if its passed an id then it will update that object.

Comment: If you can show the code for your component (maybe even your HOCs with the mutations) it would help in diagnosing this.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR;** You need to manually add newly created objects to your apollo store for the ui to update.

My answer without having seen any code: When you run a mutation, Apollo Client will automatically update anything in the store that matches the id of the object returned by the mutation with the fields that are returned. If you're creating a new object, Apollo will not find a matching object in your store to update so it won't happen automatically.

From the docs -- [Updating the Store](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/cache-updates.html):

> In some cases, just using dataIdFromObject is not enough for your 
>   application UI to update correctly. For example, if you want to add something to a list of objects without refetching the entire list, or if there are some objects that to which you can’t assign an object identifier, Apollo Client cannot update existing queries for you.

You need to manually add newly created objects to your store. Luckily there are apis available for this very thing. The piece you're looking for is the [update](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/cache-updates.html#directAccess) option.

This in tandem with [optimisticUpdate](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/cache-updates.html#directAccess) will give you the desired experience. An example of optimisticUI can be found [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/cache-updates.html#directAccess)